# Excel/VBA - For Each Loop and StringComp

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a Column from an external/closed excel sheet and compare it with an Column from an open sheet.

The problem is, that with some of my inputs, the result is false, as the comparison is not right and so the program tells me, that my array found() is not big enough for all the data

My Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim varData As Variant
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim objSheet As Object
Dim extRange As Variant
Dim intRange As Variant

Set intRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A4:A11")

Dim loopStr As Variant
Dim loopStr2 As Variant
Dim found() As Variant
Dim loopInt As Integer
Dim endStr As Variant

loopInt = 1
varData = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
If varData <> False Then
objExcel.Workbooks.Open varDatei
Set objSheets = objExcel.Sheets(1)
objSheets.Activate
LastRow = objSheets.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
Set extRange = objSheets.Range("B3:B" & LastRow)
ReDim found(1 To LastRow)
For Each loopStr In extRange
    For Each loopStr2 In intRange
        If StrComp(loopStr, loopStr2) = True Then
            found(loopInt) = loopStr
            loopInt = loopInt + 1
        End If
    Next loopStr2
Next loopStr
loopStr = ""
For Each loopStr In found
    endStr = endStr + " " + loopStr
Next loopStr
Debug.Print endStr
Else
MsgBox "Error"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you confirm what the error message says and on which line of code it appears?

Comment: You need to reset loopint as this will keep getting bigger, before the loopstr2 loop

Comment: You can use ubound(found) instead of the loopint.

Comment: Put an `Exit For` line after `loopInt = loopInt + 1`  You are continuing to look for like strings after you already found one and if there are doubles it will fill up the array prior to reaching the end of the search area.

Comment: Thanks that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

> LastRow = objSheets.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

"Rows" seems undefined to me.
Usual syntax is either

```
LastRow = objSheets.Cells(objSheets.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
```

(or whatever sheet you want to count rows for)
or

```
LastRow = objSheets.Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
```

for current sheet.
Check what debugger says about "Rows.Count".
Try this and reply if you found it useful.

Comment: I checked it, it gives me back the right number so thats not the problem. But still thanks for helping